# I was kept driving yesterday - or - I was keep driving yesterday

Tags: verbs, progressive-aspect, passive-voice

Could you please let me know which sentence is correct in terms of verb "keep" usage.

> I *was kept driving* yesterday

or

> I *was keep driving* yesterday.

I request you to give a reason for correct one that help me to understand better.

Thanks,
Charmi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was kept driving yesterday.

This sentence is in the Passive Voice: **be** + past participle (**kept**). The meaning is: someone or something kept me driving yesterday. The sentence looks a bit unnatural, but seems to be grammatical.

You can remodel this sentence to the Active Voice in a way that will change its meaning:

> I kept driving yesterday. (I continued to drive yesterday; by myself - no mention of someone or somebody "forcing" me to drive)

Your second sentence is incorrect:

> I was keep driving yesterday.

You cannot use the basic form of the verb ("keep") after "was", you've got to pick either "kept" (past participle) or "keeping" (present participle). We combine **be** with other verbs to form progressive constructions:

> I was **writing** a reply at Stack Exchange. (be + verb[ing])

and passive voice constructions:

> I was **given** 10 points for my reply at Stack Exchange. (be + past participle)

P.S. The "Keeping driving" combination would look strange though.